# Can we say that , for a parabola , no such point exists inside the parabola which is midpoint of more than one chord?

Tags: conic-sections

I was reading about the properties of parabola, amongst which one of the property was that parabola has no centre.

I tried to prove it by considering four parametric points on the parabola i.e. $P_1(a(t_1)^2,2at_1), \,P_2(a(t_2)^2,2at_2), \\P_3(a(t_3)^2,2at_3), \,P_4(a(t_4)^2,2at_4)$

Further I equated the coordinates of midpoint of $P_1P_2$ and $P_3P_4$, after  doing this I got that either $P1=P3$ and $P_2=P_4$ or $P_1=P_4$ and $P_2=P_3$, i.e. the two chords are coincident .

So from the above observation can I conclude that for a parabola a point which lies inside the parabola cannot be the midpoint of more than one chord?

Comment: Assuming all your working is correct, then yes, this is a valid interpretation of the given conclusion. The point is that $\{P_1, P_2\} = \{P_3, P_4\}$, as unordered sets, showing that there is a unique unordered pair of points whose midpoint is the given point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(x,y)$ be a point satisfying $y > x^2$.  Then the system $$\begin{align}
x &= \frac{x_1 + x_2}{2}, \\
y &= \frac{x_1^2 + x_2^2}{2}
\end{align}$$ has, up to permutation of $x_1, x_2$, the unique solution $$x_1 = x \pm \sqrt{y-x^2}, \quad x_2 = x \mp \sqrt{y-x^2}.$$  It follows that for each "interior" point of the parabola $y = x^2$, there is precisely one pair of points $(x_1, x_1^2)$, $(x_2, x_2^2)$ on the parabola whose midpoint is $(x,y)$.  Since all nondegenerate parabolas are similar, the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

A well-known property of parabolas states that

> the midpoints of parallel chords all lie on a line parallel to the
> axis, and the tangent at the intersection point between that line and
> the parabola is parallel to the chords.

This implies that two different chords cannot have the same midpoint.